# Windows 10 Search does NOT index Outlook 365 mails fully

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search-indexing

I have around 400K (four hundred thousand) mails across all my folders in Outlook Mail IMAP profile stored in .ost file.

Initially, Windows 10 Search will NOT index these mails at all.

However, after trying to [Rebuild the Index multiple times](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fix-search-issues-by-rebuildling-your-instant-search-catalog-213a2728-0ef4-427a-9bb2-aed329a59b17), Restarting the Windows Search service, ensuring that Outlook Mail is included in Search Locations (only other items in Search Locations is Start Menu and Users (to ensure that all Outlook emails including attachments do get indexed first), it did start indexing. I also ran the Trouble shooter for Windows Search and it did fix some permissions on indexed folders but not helped any further.

However, in spite of the Outlook .ost having around 400K mails, Indexing Complete is displayed with a number 113743 items indexed.

How do I ensure that all the emails including attachments are indexed ?

Thanking in advance,

Regards,

Comment: Work-aropund: For more complete indexing, a third-party tool such as DocFetcher, http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/ , is useful. In  addition, it can index formats such as EPUB and ODT, which at one time, MS Search could not (they may have fixed that omission by now).

Comment: Did you try the options at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/troubleshooting-outlook-search-issues-2556b11f-f4d8-46be-b0a7-de33a3f4f066#bkmk_incompleteresults

Comment: Please refer to the threads: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/85e3fda2-6636-4292-b798-2b2f27b32e63/windows-10-outlook-365-search-does-not-work-anymore-indexing-doesnt-seem-to-pick-up-outlook?forum=outlook and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f4659156-f63b-4909-95da-2c44ab3181b1/outlook-searching-issue?forum=outlook